# Perl can't locate object method "query_form" via package "URI::_foreign" at Geo::Coder::Google::V3.pm

Tags: perl, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, amazon-ec2

I understand this question has been asked in different forms before.

Here is the line in `Google::V3.pm`:

```
use lib '/var/www/cgi-bin/lib';
use Carp;
use Encode;
use JSON;
use HTTP::Request;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use URI;

...

my $uri = URI->new("http://$self->{host}/maps/api/geocode/json");
my %query_parameters = ($loc_param => $location);

...

my $components_params = $self->_get_components_query_params;
$query_parameters{components} = $components_params if defined $components_params;
$uri->query_form(%query_parameters);
my $url = $uri->as_string;
```

Here's the code from URI::_foreign.pm:

```
package URI::_foreign;

require URI::_generic;
@ISA=qw(URI::_generic);

1;
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What's the output of `use Data::Dumper; print(Dumper($uri));` right before the error? I don't think what you posted it representative of the `$uri` you actually had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`URI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) constructor creates an object instance specific to the scheme of the data passed to it.  For http data, that is [`URI::http`](https://metacpan.org/source/GAAS/URI-1.60/URI/http.pm).  However, if it's unable to determine a scheme, the final fall back is of class [`URI::_foreign`](https://metacpan.org/source/GAAS/URI-1.60/URI/_foreign.pm).

Each of these subclasses have different abilities and features.  As you've observed, the base class `_foreign` does not have an implementation of `query_form`.

So our question why is your data not being interpreted as `http`?  I also think, like ikegami, that what you posted is not representative of the `$uri` you actually had.

Here is a script that shows how `URI` will interpret data specific to the scheme:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use URI;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;

    my $u = URI->new($_);
    printf "%-13s - %s\n", ref($u), $u;
}

__DATA__
http://www.asdf.com
http://www.asdf.com/morestuff
http://////too_many_slashes_still_ok
ftp://ftp.asdf.com/
gopher://oldtimey.com/
unknown://www.asdf.com/
```

outputs:

```
URI::http     - http://www.asdf.com
URI::http     - http://www.asdf.com/morestuff
URI::http     - http://////too_many_slashes_still_ok
URI::ftp      - ftp://ftp.asdf.com/
URI::gopher   - gopher://oldtimey.com/
URI::_foreign - unknown://www.asdf.com/
```